# How to change icon color when input field is focus input field is from another div - HTML - CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to change placeholder and icon color when input block is focus and filled with text.

1. add input field with icon and placeholder that showing color when its not focus as did in code.
2. change icon and placeholder color when input focus.
   a. This is working for placeholder.
   b.not working for icon. NEED HELP HERE

Here is code link - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZTM5JKXA5D2

I try this but not working

```
 .inputBlock input:focus i {
      z-index: 1;
      position: absolute;
      color: #ffffff;
      left: 4px;
      top: 17px;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <style>


    .inputBlock {
      margin: 10px 0;
      width: 600px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .inputBlock input {
      padding: 17px 25px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .inputBlock i {
      z-index: 1;
      position: absolute;
      color: #0082D4;
      left: 4px;
      top: 17px;
    }

    .inputBlock input:focus i {
      z-index: 1;
      position: absolute;
      color: #ffffff;
      left: 4px;
      top: 17px;
    }

    .inputBlock input::-moz-placeholder {
      color: #0082D4;
    }

    .inputBlock input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #0082D4;
    }

    .inputBlock input:focus::-moz-placeholder  {
      color: #8B9DA7;
      border-color: #0082D4;
    }

    .inputBlock input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #8B9DA7;
      border-color: #0082D4;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="inputBlock"><div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add input"> </input></div>
    <i class="fa fa-car"> </i>
    </div>



    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: please check again . this code i  was miss to add another div for input. '
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZTMTKSSDXFE

Answer (score 1):

You could do it easily in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").focus(function() {
        $(".fa-car").css("color", "red");
    }).blur(function() {
        $(".fa-car").css("color", "#0082D4");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input:focus + .fa.fa-car {
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: not working because this input block is from another  div

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your css selector:

```
.inputBlock input:focus i {
```

This selects an i element *inside* a focused input *inside* the inputBlock-div. your `<i>` is a sibling of the input, not a descendent, you therfore need to use either the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) or the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) like this:

```
.inputBlock input:focus + i {
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how can i select form this <div class="inputBlock">
<div class="inputClass">
<input type="text"  placeholder="Add input"> </input></div>
<i class="fa fa-user"> </i>
</div>

Comment: You can not. CSS (presently) does not allow such a selection and you would be limited to a JavaScript/jQuery/... solution, like the one @Lukas shows in his answer. If you want to do it with CSS alone, you'd have to place that `<I>` _inside_ the inputClass-<DIV>.